# Permission to read write and delete files in a folder but not the folder itself

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

Is there a way to set permissions so that a folder belongs to root or to a particular group (it doesn't matter) and the folder itself cannot be deleted by the group but this doesn't apply to the content of the folder (files or folder contained in that folder) ?
Or maybe if not possible ...is it possible to not allow to users to remove a folder if the folder contains files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not you can delete the folder itself or not depends on the permissions of the directory where that folder is located in. So, you could have a setup like this:

```
/home        (belongs to root, 755)
/home/user   (belongs to user, 755)
```

Then the user can create and delete files and folders in `/home/user`, but not `/home/user` itself. ;)

Comment: Be very careful with that :-P, do not use a real user's home to test

Comment: Yes, it was meant as an example and to show that usecases like that already exist...

Comment: it seems to work but on FTP when the user attempts to remove folder /home/user ..an error occurs and that's ok but for some unknown reasons..all the files in /home/user are deleted without notification.

Comment: Check the server logs then. Either the ftp client or the ftp server is recursively deleting the files in the directory then, out of convenience.